# executing a block if a variable is not null

Tags: azure, terraform

I am using **azurerm_private_endpoint**. For this we can define two blocks  **private_service_connection** and **private_dns_zone_group** as the following:

```
resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "example" {
  name                = "example-endpoint"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.example.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "example-privateserviceconnection"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id
    subresource_names              = ["blob"]
    is_manual_connection           = false
  }

  private_dns_zone_group {
    name                 = "example-dns-zone-group"
    private_dns_zone_ids = [azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.id]
  }
}
```

I would like to have private_dns_zone_group if the appropriat variable is not null

```
azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.id != null
```

something like this:

```
private_dns_zone_group {
    count= azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.id ==null ? 0 : 1
    name                 = "example-dns-zone-group"
    private_dns_zone_ids = [azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.id]
  }
```

but it seems, that is not the correct approach. does some one has a better idea to achieve this aim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tired Conditionally Including `private_dns_zone_group` in AzureRM Private Endpoint with Dynamic Blocks and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

You cannot use the same approach for conditionally including a block based on a variable's value (like `private_dns_zone_group` based on whether `azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.id` is not null) inside resource blocks in Terraform as you would outside of them. This is because Terraform's syntax for conditional expressions does not allow adding or removing whole blocks depending on conditions. You can use dynamic blocks to achieve conditional logic for resource blocks instead.

A resource definition can use the `dynamic` block to create multiple nested blocks like `private_dns_zone_group` depending on the value of a variable or expression. To include the `private_dns_zone_group` in your `azurerm_private_endpoint` resource only when certain conditions are met, you can combine `dynamic` blocks and conditional expressions.

The following Terraform configuration shows how to use the `private_dns_zone_group` argument in an `azurerm_private_endpoint` resource only when needed. This configuration also creates the required resources (`azurerm_resource_group`, `azurerm_subnet`, `azurerm_storage_account`, and `azurerm_private_dns_zone`) to provide a complete and coherent example.

**My terraform configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "demorg-vksb"
  location = "East US"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "demovk-vnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "demovk-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
  service_endpoints    = ["Microsoft.Storage"]
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "vksbbstorageacc"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "example" {

  name                = "privatelink.blob.core.windows.net"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

variable "create_private_dns_zone_group" {
  description = "Determines if the private DNS zone group should be created"
  type        = bool
  default     = true 
}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "example" {
  name                = "demovk-endpoint"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.example.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "demovk-privateserviceconnection"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id
    subresource_names              = ["blob"]
    is_manual_connection           = false
  }

  dynamic "private_dns_zone_group" {
    for_each = var.create_private_dns_zone_group ? [1] : []
    content {
      name                 = "demovk-dns-zone-group"
      private_dns_zone_ids = [azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.id]
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]